# Oracle XMLTABLE Function. How to merge nodes that have the same name?

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-parsing, oracle-sqldeveloper, xmltable

**The Post was Edited to provide a minimal reproducible example**

I'm looking for a way to concatenate all name nodes(could be 2-3-4 etc) together with space between them. The following example gives error `ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence`. I know this is because there are multiple name nodes.

I tried replacing

`"name"        VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'name'` with

`"name"        VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'name[1]'` which would give only the first value. That removes the error but is not concatenating them together.

```
WITH XML_T (XML_FILE_DATA) AS (SELECT '<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <name>Cake</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles(2)</name>
        <name>Cake(2)</name>
        <price>$5.95(2)</price>
        <calories>650(2)</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>' FROM DUAL)
SELECT x.*
  FROM XML_T,
       XMLTABLE ('/breakfast_menu/food'
                 PASSING xmltype (XML_T.XML_FILE_DATA)
                 COLUMNS    "name"        VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'name',
                            "price"       VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'price',
                            "calories"    VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'calories') X;
```

I want to be able to get the 2 names and merge them together in a column. Desired Output:

```
+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| name                    |       price |    calories |
+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| Belgian Waffles Cake    |       $5.95 |         650 |
| Belgian Waffles Cake(2) |    $5.95(2) |      650(2) |
+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

@Padders Answer solved the problem.

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**: 
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and SQL that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.

Comment: I tried my best to write it, I have the xml, the logic and the sql that I used. The only thing I can think of to do better is to give an example like in the answer I received with the xml included in the PL/SQL but I didn't knew how to include it, because I have it in a table. And the desired output I wrote that I want to merge the nodes into ```Belgian Waffles Cake``` .

Comment: @Yitzhak Khabinsky  I will try to make an edit to the post later to make it easier to understand and try to get it closer to a minimal reproducible example. I'm guessing the best would be to have a piece of code that you can copy paste it to test it. But should I make an edit additional to my initial post, or to modify what I wrote and change the way it is?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of Oracle's support for xquery expressions in the PATH string, e.g.

```
SELECT xt.*
FROM   xml_t x,
       XMLTABLE (
           'breakfast_menu/food'
           PASSING x.xml_file_data
           COLUMNS
              names VARCHAR2 (4000) PATH 'string-join(name," ")',
              price VARCHAR2 (50) PATH 'price',
              calories VARCHAR2 (50) PATH 'calories') xt;
```

Comment: I think this might be the best way for doing this. It great, easy to understand and it seems to be working no matter how many nodes I have. I'm no expert but this seems better than the first answer

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify which **name** you are looking for in your XPath selector like this:

```sql
WITH xml_t (xml_file_data) AS (SELECT '<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <name>Cake</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles(2)</name>
        <name>Cake(2)</name>
        <price>$5.95(2)</price>
        <calories>650(2)</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>' FROM DUAL)
SELECT TRIM (name1 || ' ' || name2 || ' ' || name3 || ' ' || name4) AS combined_names, x.*
  FROM xml_t,
       XMLTABLE ('/breakfast_menu/food'
                 PASSING xmltype (XML_T.XML_FILE_DATA)
                 COLUMNS name1 VARCHAR2 (50) PATH 'name[1]',
                         name2 VARCHAR2 (50) PATH 'name[2]',
                         name3 VARCHAR2 (50) PATH 'name[3]',
                         name4 VARCHAR2 (50) PATH 'name[4]',
                         price VARCHAR2 (50) PATH 'price',
                         calories VARCHAR2 (50) PATH 'calories') X;



               COMBINED_NAMES                 NAME1      NAME2    NAME3    NAME4       PRICE    CALORIES
_____________________________ _____________________ __________ ________ ________ ___________ ___________
Belgian Waffles Cake          Belgian Waffles       Cake                         $5.95       650
Belgian Waffles(2) Cake(2)    Belgian Waffles(2)    Cake(2)                      $5.95(2)    650(2)
```

Comment: I want to have the name columns combined and not have them as sepparate columns. ```"name1" VARCHAR2 (50) PATH 'name[1]',
  "name2" VARCHAR2 (50) PATH 'name[2]',``` If I delete these 2 columns will it still work? It seems to give error to me

Comment: Basically it's good how the result looks, just without name1 and name 2 columns. so it has only 3 columns : COMBINED_NAMES, PRICE and CALORIES

Comment: All you have to do is modify the columns you are selecting like `SELECT TRIM (name1 || ' ' || name2 || ' ' || name3 || ' ' || name4) AS combined_names, x.price, x.calories FROM....`

Comment: After modifying ```AS combined_names, x.price, x.calories FROM``` it has the desired output. So you put all the columns and you just Select the ones you need. One question: If i have more names i would just continue to add ```nameX VARCHAR2 (50) PATH 'name[X]',``` and so on? Besides that Thanks a lot it helps! :)

Comment: yes, you can just continue to add additional `nameX` columns to your list of columns in your XMLTABLE expression, then concatenate them in your COMBINED_NAMES column.